# How to skip some elements on HTML to get custom CSS style

Tags: html, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I don't want to the first two images get the custome style I wrote.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="entry">
  <img src="image1.jpg">
  <img src="image2.jpg">
  <img src="image3.jpg">
  <img src="image4.jpg">
  <img src="image5.jpg">
</div>
```

I've just try this:

```
.entry img:not(:first-of-type):not(:nth-of-type(2)) {
  margin: 0 auto 20px !important;
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

But it's not working
And these:

```
.entry img:not(:nth-child(-n+2)) {
  margin: 0 auto 20px !important;
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```
.entry img:not(:first-child):not(:nth-child(2)) {
    margin: 0 auto 20px !important;
    display: block;
    width: 350px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

Comment: All of your examples work as they are. We need a complete reproducible example.

Comment: Your actual HTML does not reflect what you're presenting, so you'll get bad answers. Make sure that the example simulates the real scenario as close as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:

```css
 .entry img:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(2)) {
      margin: 0 auto 20px !important;
      display: block;
      width: 350px;
      height: 250px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="entry">
    <img src="image1.jpg">
    <img src="image2.jpg">
    <img src="image3.jpg">
    <img src="image4.jpg">
    <img src="image5.jpg">
 </div>
```

Comment: Still not working. This is the page:
https://coralspringstalk.com/j-p-taravella-anthony-quigley-47290

Comment: I changed the code so you can run it and see that it's working. I think the problem might be somewhere else in your codes. can you share more details? for example where on your website are your pictures? Or can you share the code for that part?

Comment: This is the link to the page: 
https://coralspringstalk.com/city-discusses-preliminary-2024-budget-47272
I want to skip the first two pictures (red) at the beginning of the main layout content, but the rest (blue) get the style.
Here is a screenshot of the page: https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/6bc4818e-05a3-410d-9712-a11b06b11d77
maziar-rumiani

Answer (score 0):

Try this css selector, to select all images except the first two:

```
.entry > img:not(img:nth-child(1),img:nth-child(2))
{
   /* whatever styles you want for all img exept 1 and 2 */ 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working in my case! 
This is the link to the page: https://coralspringstalk.com/city-discusses-preliminary-2024-budget-47272
And this is a screenshot that specifies whether the image should (blue) or should not (red)get the style: 
https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/6bc4818e-05a3-410d-9712-a11b06b11d77

Comment: @obeidarash looking at the page your HTML structure looks completely different inside .entry,

Answer (score 0):

Call first ones `image` and others `img`.

img{} and image{} shall be different.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use :nth-child(n + x)

```
<div class="entry">
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

```
.entry p:nth-child(n + 3) {
  color: red;
}
```